# Frame rate change in windows fours VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, winforms

I am creating a game in which small pictureboxes move quickly across the screen. My monitor's refresh rate is 144Hz and it works fine, but when I put it down to 60Hz on some frames the picture box cant be seen or gets clipped.

Any way to alter the FPS the window runs at to avoid this clipping?
(i assume it rins at the same refresh rate as monitor)

Comment: A reference you may need : [https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/976799ff-05d9-4fea-a061-9142ec0b2f2a/remove-flicker-from-picturebox-here-we-go-again?forum=vbgeneral](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/976799ff-05d9-4fea-a061-9142ec0b2f2a/remove-flicker-from-picturebox-here-we-go-again?forum=vbgeneral)